# Is it possible to have several entries in a bibtex-date field?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

My documents are often referring to articles that span several issues of the same journal, as in the following example. In building the file, `biber` complains that this would not be a correct `date` format and accordingly, the date is omitted from the reference output.

This is kind of an expected behaviour since the `bibtex` date format has to be YYYY-MM-DD, as I understand it.

But: is there a way to include several dates for an article?

Here is the example:

```
@ARTICLE{Lazarus1856,
  author = {Lazarus},
  title = {Hebräische Poesie},
  journal = {Literaturblatt des Deutschen Kunstblatts},
  volume = {3},
  year = {1856},
  pages = {6-8, 11-12},
  number = {2,3},
  date = {1856-01-24,1856-02-07},
  timestamp = {2011.12.12}
}
```

I'm using JabRef, TexLive, Kile, XeLaTex, Biblatex-Biber.

Comment: There's an `eventdate` field. I've never used though, and the documentation for `biblatex` doesn't say much about it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  I would be inclined to make an EntrySet out of the different parts.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina: If I understand it correctly, you can have date _spans_, but not several separated dates - notwithstanding if it's ´date´, ´eventdate´ or ´origdate´.

Comment: You can have date spans, but not two dates in the `date` fields. The (maybe in some cases too simplifying) idea being that a particular work will have been published at one exact date (spans then are for multi-volumes, or for conference dates etc.). In your case, however I would go for two different `.bib` entries, both works are separated by the fact that they appeared in different `numbers` of a journal (not even on consecutive pages), maybe combined into one `@set`.

Comment: See also [Serial Articles -- Articles in Installments / relatedtype=serial](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/272).

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I tried splitting the entry in two and binding them again via a `@set`. But both versions of bundling failed: using an `entryset = {entry1, entry2}` field resulted in a simple list of both full entries. And using `related = {entry1; entry2}` as suggested in the Serial Articles link above (but without the undefined `relatedtype=serial` field) lead biber exit with code 1 because it did not find the related entries. Is `relatedtype` and the insertion of the code mentioned at github needed? If yes - where?

Comment: I used eventdate and date separately with ``biblatex`` before for academic conferences, where date was for the date of the publication of the proceedigns and the evendate marked the actual conference date as a date range.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to add multiple dates to any of `biblatex`'s standard date fields. `date` fields must be populated in ISO 8601/EDTF format and Biber will ignore malformed fields. That means you can add a date span (interval), but that is not what we want here.

Normally, a work is published on one specific date and there is no need for multiple dates.
One of the few cases where this is actually a problem is in cases of multiple instalments of an article or multi-volume books. `biblatex` can deal with multi-volume books quite well out of the box, so we will focus on adding a similar support for series articles.

We will have a look at how `biblatex` handles multi-volume books first. In `biblatex-examples.bib` you will find

```
@book{knuth:ct:related,
  author       = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title        = {Computers \& Typesetting},
  date         = {1984/1986},
  volumes      = 5,
  publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
  location     = {Reading, Mass.},
  sortyear     = {1984-0},
  related      = {knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d,knuth:ct:e},
  relatedtype  = {multivolume},
}
```

And then separate entries for all the volumes `knuth:ct:a` etc.

Some time ago there was a [feature request about this on the `biblatex` bugtracker](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/272).
We will follow the idea there. Analogously to the `multivolume` approach above we create a `relatedtype` `serialarticle`.
For related `serialarticle`s only `volume`, `number`, (`eid`, `issue`), `date` and the `pages` are printed (of course this could be extended to print additional fields, such as DOIs and URLs).

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{related:serialarticle}{#1}
\renewcommand*{\relateddelim}{\adddot\par\nobreak}
\newcommand*{\relateddelimserialarticle}{\addcomma\space}

\newbibmacro*{related:serialarticle}[1]{%
  \entrydata{#1}{%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \iffieldundef{pages}
    {}
    {\setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
     \printfield{pages}}}}
```

Your example then would look like this

```
@article{Lazarus1856,
  author      = {Lazarus},
  title       = {Hebräische Poesie},
  journal     = {Literaturblatt des Deutschen Kunstblatts},
  volume      = {3},
  date        = {1856},
  related     = {Lazarus1856-1,Lazarus1856-2},
  relatedtype = {serialarticle},
}
@article{Lazarus1856-1,
  crossref  = {Lazarus1856},
  pages     = {6-8},
  number    = {2},
  date      = {1856-01-24},
  options   = {dataonly},
}
@article{Lazarus1856-2,
  crossref  = {Lazarus1856},
  pages     = {11-12},
  number    = {3},
  date      = {1856-02-07},
  options   = {dataonly},
}
```

It consist of a "main" entry that contains the invariants (`author`, `title`, also `volume`, should also have a `date`/`year`) and two `dataonly` entries for the actual parts that contains the `number`, `date` and `pages` (we also `crossref` it back to `Lazarus1856` such that the two entries could also stand on their own).
The main entry relates back to its parts just like a multi-volume book does

```
  related     = {Lazarus1856-1,Lazarus1856-2},
  relatedtype = {serialarticle},
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{related:serialarticle}{#1}
\renewcommand*{\relateddelim}{\adddot\par\nobreak}
\newcommand*{\relateddelimserialarticle}{\addcomma\space}

\newbibmacro*{related:serialarticle}[1]{%
  \entrydata{#1}{%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \iffieldundef{pages}
    {}
    {\setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
     \printfield{pages}}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Lazarus1856,
  author      = {Lazarus},
  title       = {Hebräische Poesie},
  journal     = {Literaturblatt des Deutschen Kunstblatts},
  volume      = {3},
  date        = {1856},
  related     = {Lazarus1856-1,Lazarus1856-2},
  relatedtype = {serialarticle},
}
@article{Lazarus1856-1,
  crossref  = {Lazarus1856},
  pages     = {6-8},
  number    = {2},
  date      = {1856-01-24},
  options   = {dataonly},
}
@article{Lazarus1856-2,
  crossref  = {Lazarus1856},
  pages     = {11-12},
  number    = {3},
  date      = {1856-02-07},
  options   = {dataonly},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{Lazarus1856,knuth:ct:related}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lazarus. “Hebräische Poesie”. In: Literaturblatt des Deutschen Kunstblatts 3 (1856). 3.2 (Jan. 24, 1856), pp. 6–8, 3.3 (Feb. 7, 1856), pp. 11–12.]

Comment: This awesome answer resolves my question. One small additional question: Where would I put a `nobreak` or the like, in order to have the serial entries on the same line as the main entry, just separated by semicolons or commata?

Comment: @shevek This is done with `\relateddelim`, I have added a solution to my answer that adds a comma.

Comment: Great, that is exactly the solution for my problem. Thank you, moewe, for your great help, and sorry, I have to express my appreciation this way because I do not have enough repution yet to vote your answer up.

Answer (score 0):

This is fiendishly clever.  But isn't it also a bit insane?

If I'm cataloguing a two-volume book, where each volume was published in a different year, then it should be possible to say "date = {1996, 1997}".  It's that simple. It's common sense. Rather than the verbose solution given above, biber/biblatex should be altered slightly to accomodate the real-world situation.

I guess the workaround is to use the year field.

Comment: Actually, a multi-volume book is handled out of the box by biblatex, as is shown with the Knuth book case in moewe's answer. It is enough to use the existing `related` field and `relatedtype  = {multivolume}`.

Comment: It is possible to say `date = {1996/1997}` for date ranges (following ISO 8601/EDTF standard). The `date` field needs to be a valid date range, it can not be arbitrary input as it needs to be parsed.

Comment: sure.  But that gives "1993-1997" instead of "1993, 1997".  Two volumes are not published across several years, but at specific dates.  A better example would be three or more volumes.

Comment: Thank you, @gusbrs, this does work.  But the output is like the Knuth volumes above, with a new block for each volume.  In Humanities, one typically wants bibliography entries like this:

Ram, Labhu and Bala Sahai Shastri (1932, 1941). Catalogue of Sanskrit
Manuscripts in the Panjab University Library.  2 vols. Lahore:
Labhu Ram, Librarian for the University of the Panjab.

Answer (score 0):

Treating the years as string literals could work, although the effect when there are many of them is not elegant.
Such a construct could be used to list all the editions of a work, for example.

===

It is possible to get Biblatex to print a sequence of "years" in a citation

[image: multi years]

but it means not using date fields at all and treating the years as a list of one-word literals.

In Biblatex, date fields, like `date`, are a datetime, or a datetime span, and are automatically parsed into day, month, year (and hour, minute, second) components (and endday, endmonth, etc).

Name lists, like `author` and `editor`, are lists of names separated by " and ", and are parsed into name-parts (given name, family name, etc). A one-word name, like "Aristotle", is treated as a family name.

So if we have an entry like this

```
@book{twee,Author ={Foo Barnum Tweedledee and Bar Bailey Tweedledum},date ={1873},title={A Series of Peripatetic Encounters with Interesting People},location={London and New York},}
```

the family names are printed in the citation (using an author-title style like ext-authortitle):

[image: family name]

If we have a multi-author work like this

```
@book{ancgreek,Title ={The IP of Classical Greece\textsuperscript{ver1}},date={-0500/-0300},author={Aristotle and Plato and  Socrates and Archimedes and Euclid and Pericles and Aristophanes and Pindar and Homer},}
```

`et al` (or `and others`) truncates the author list when there are more than the default of 3

[image: Aristotle and friends]

We can adjust the `et al` threshold with the `maxnames` and related options (here in the entry itself),

```
@book{ancgreek2,Title ={The IP of Classical Greece\textsuperscript{ver2}},date={-0499/-0299},author={Aristotle and Plato and  Socrates and Archimedes and Euclid and Pericles and Aristophanes and Pindar and Homer},options = {maxnames=50},}
```

to get the fuller list of (comma-separated) names.

[image: Aristotle and everyone else]

A third Biblatex datatype is a literal list, which is a list of names (such as publishers, or locations) which are separated by " and " and are not split into name parts and stored in name part fields.

Back to our years:

We'll use a literal list to store our string of years. Let's call it `datestext`.

We need to add the field to the datamodel, with

```
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list, datatype=literal]{
  datestext,
}
```

which has to live in a `.dbx` file. Let's call the file `dmf_dt.dbx` and tell Biblatex about it with the `datamodel` option:

```
datamodel=dmf_dt,
```

Now we need a new bibmacro that will print the list and enclose it in parentheses.

But: `\mkbibparens{\printlist{datestext}}` lives under the spell of the `et al` threshold

[image: years et al]

and not even a `maxnames` counterspell will remove it. (`Publisher` and `location` suffer the same `et al` fate.)

Fortunately, `\printlist` can do loops, from 1 to the end of the list: `\printlist[][1-\value{listtotal}]{datestext}`.

Lastly, we need a `\DeclareCiteCommand` to define a new cite command (call it `citedatestext`) that will invoke the bibmacro. For convenience, we'll also print the title field at the same time (with `\printfield{title}`, rather than a `usebibmacro{title}` which introduces space and punctuation).

[image: looping through the Chronicles]

Of course, the years only look like dates. They are not "real" dates where Biblatex can apply its powerful date and era calculations. Any sequence of strings can go into the literal list.

[image: arbitrary strings]

Note: just the citation command has been defined in this thought experiment; the references print "as normal" in the bibliography. A new or modified bibliography driver would be needed to handle the new field.

DBX:

```
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list, datatype=literal]{
  datestext,
}
```

MWE:

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: biber
% arara: xelatex 
\RequirePackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@book{lewis,Author ={C S Lewis},date ={1898/1963},}


@book{twee,Author ={Foo Barnum Tweedledee and Bar Bailey Tweedledum},date ={1873},title={A Series of Peripatetic Encounters with Interesting People},location={London and New York},}

@book{twee2,Author ={Foo Barnum Tweedledee and Bar Bailey Tweedledum and Alice Goldilocks},date ={1876},title={Further Peripatetic Encounters with Interesting People},location={London and New York and Paris and Rome},}

%@book{chroniclesofnarnia,Title ={The Chronicles of Narnia},crossref ={lewis},sortkey ={Chronicles of Narnia},keywords ={series, school},}
%
%@book{chroniclesofnarnia2,Title ={The Chronicles of Narnia2},date={1950/1956},sortkey ={Chronicles of Narnia},keywords ={series, school},}

@book{ancgreek,Title ={The IP of Classical Greece\textsuperscript{ver1}},date={-0500/-0300},author={Aristotle and Plato and  Socrates and Archimedes and Euclid and Pericles and Aristophanes and Pindar and Homer},}

@book{ancgreek2,Title ={The IP of Classical Greece\textsuperscript{ver2}},date={-0499/-0299},author={Aristotle and Plato and  Socrates and Archimedes and Euclid and Pericles and Aristophanes and Pindar and Homer},options = {maxnames=50},}

@book{ancgreek3,Title ={IP of Classical Greece -- the Reflowering},subtitle={The Renaissance},date={1400/1500},author={Aristotle and Plato and  Socrates and Archimedes and Euclid and Pericles and Aristophanes and Pindar and Homer},options = {maxnames=50},}

@book{chroniclesofnarnia3a,Title ={The Chronicles of Narnia\textsuperscript{ver3a}},date={1950/1956},sortkey ={Chronicles of Narnia},crossref ={lewis},keywords ={series, school},
datestext={1950 and 1951 and 1952 and 1953 and 1954 and 1955 and 1956},
%options = {maxnames=999},
}

@book{chroniclesofnarnia3a1,Title ={The Chronicles of Narnia},date={1950/1956},sortkey ={Chronicles of Narnia},crossref ={lewis},keywords ={series, school},
datestext={1950 and 1951 and 1952 and 1953 and 1954 and 1955 and 1956},
options = {maxnames=999},
}


@book{chroniclesofnarnia3b,Title ={The Chronicles of Narnia\textsuperscript{ver3b}},date={1950/1956},sortkey ={Chronicles of Narnia},crossref ={lewis},keywords ={series, school},
datestext={1950 and 1951 and 1952 and 1953 and 1954 and 1955 and 1956},
options = {maxnames=999},
}

@book{chroniclesofnarnia3c,Title ={The Chronicles of Narnia\textsuperscript{ver3c}},date={1950/1956},sortkey ={Chronicles of Narnia},crossref ={lewis},keywords ={series, school},
datestext={1950 and 1951 and 1952 and 1953 and 1954 and 1955 and 1956},
%options = {maxnames=999},
}
@book{chroniclesofnarnia4,Title ={The Chronicles of Narnia\textsuperscript{ver4}},date={1950/1956},sortkey ={Chronicles of Narnia},crossref ={lewis},keywords ={series, school},
datestext={book 1 and {Susan and Peter} and something about a chair and string and string and string and book 7},options = {maxnames=999},
}


@book{bsm27,Title ={The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe },Date ={1950},Series ={Chronicles of Narnia},Number ={1},xref ={chroniclesofnarnia},sortkey ={Chronicles of Narnia01},shorthand ={CSL--N1},keywords ={series},}
@book{bsm28,Title ={Prince Caspian },Date ={1951},Series ={Chronicles of Narnia},Number ={2},xref ={chroniclesofnarnia},sortkey ={Chronicles of Narnia02},shorthand ={CSL--N2},keywords ={series},}
@book{bsm29,Title ={The Voyage of the Dawn Treader },Date ={1952},Series ={Chronicles of Narnia},Number ={3},xref ={chroniclesofnarnia},sortkey ={Chronicles of Narnia03},shorthand ={CSL--N3},keywords ={series},}
@book{bsm30,Title ={The Silver Chair },Date ={1953},Series ={Chronicles of Narnia},Number ={4},xref ={chroniclesofnarnia},sortkey ={Chronicles of Narnia04},shorthand ={CSL--N4},keywords ={series},}
@book{bsm31,Title ={The Horse and His Boy },Date ={1954},Series ={Chronicles of Narnia},Number ={5},xref ={chroniclesofnarnia},sortkey ={Chronicles of Narnia05},shorthand ={CSL--N5},keywords ={series},}
@book{bsm32,Title ={The Magician's Nephew },Date ={1955},Series ={Chronicles of Narnia},Number ={6},xref ={chroniclesofnarnia},sortkey ={Chronicles of Narnia06},shorthand ={CSL--N6},keywords ={series},}
@book{bsm33,Title ={The Last Battle },Date ={1956},Series ={Chronicles of Narnia},Number ={7},xref ={chroniclesofnarnia},sortkey ={Chronicles of Narnia07},shorthand ={CSL--N7},keywords ={series},}

\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\newcommand\abibname{ext-authortitle}
\newcommand\abibstyle{style=\abibname}
\usepackage[
    datamodel=dmf_dt,
    \abibstyle , 
%maxnames=99,
%minnames=99,
%maxcitenames=99,
%mincitenames=99,   
dateera=christian,
        ]{biblatex}
\newcommand\mynote{biblatex option used: \texttt{\abibstyle}.}
\defbibnote{abibnote}{\mynote}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{red!3}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[book]{maxnames=99}

\newbibmacro*{possum}{%
\mkbibparens{\printlist[][1-\value{listtotal}]{datestext}}}    


\newbibmacro*{possum2}{%
\mkbibparens{\printlist{datestext}}}    




\DeclareCiteCommand{citedatestext}[]{}{%
\printfield{title}  \usebibmacro{possum}}{}{}

\DeclareCiteCommand{citedatestextb}[]{}{%
\printfield{title}  \usebibmacro{possum2}}{}{}

%  \DeclareCiteCommand{\longcite}
%  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
%  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
%   \defcounter{maxnames}{99}%
%   \usebibmacro{cite}}
%  {\multicitedelim}
%  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

%  \newtoggle{bbx:allnames}
%\togglefalse{bbx:allnames}
%\AtEveryBibitem{\iftoggle{bbx:allnames}{\defcounter{maxnames}{999}}{}}


\begin{document}

\citedatestext{chroniclesofnarnia3a1}
\vskip1em

\cite{twee}
\vskip1em

%\cite{twee2}

 \cite{ancgreek}
\vskip1em

 \cite{ancgreek2}
\vskip1em 

% \cite{ancgreek3}

 \citedatestextb{chroniclesofnarnia3a} -- without maxnames=, with plain \textbackslash \texttt{printlist}
\vskip1em

\citedatestextb{chroniclesofnarnia3b} -- with maxnames=,with plain \textbackslash \texttt{printlist}
\vskip1em

\citedatestext{chroniclesofnarnia3c} -- with looping \textbackslash \texttt{printlist}
\vskip1em

\citedatestext{chroniclesofnarnia4} -- arbitrary strings





\printbibliography[prenote=abibnote]


\begin{center}
\textemdash
\textemdash
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since `datestext` is a list and not a name list, the counterspell that would help here is `maxitems` instead of `maxnames`. Of course one could turn `datestext` directly into a normal literal field instead of a list and would not have to worry about that at all. As you mention one would have to modify the bibliography style to honour `datestext` and one would also have to make sure that sorting works as expected. This is quite tricky since Biber usually expects the year of a `date` to be an integer and it can't sort integers and strings at the same time.