# how to reference multi-part article with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

With the following MWE I do not get the desired output.

```
\begin{filecontents}{lit.bib}
@article{Heuberger99,
    author={Heuberger, Albert and Volker Gehrmann},
    title={{Störsichere Übertragung in den ISM-Bändern}},
    journal={Elektronik},
    year= 1999,
    pages={{74--78 und 90--95}},
    number={{19 und 20}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,sorting=nyt,natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{lit.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Instead I get

*Heuberger, Albert und Volker Gehrmann (1999). »Störsichere Übertragung in den ISM-Bändern«. In: Elektronik 19 und 20, pages.*

What *I* expect (or at least what I would like to get) is

*Heuberger, Albert und Volker Gehrmann (1999). »Störsichere Übertragung in den ISM-Bändern«. In: Elektronik 19 und 20, S. 74--78 und 90--95.*

or something similar.

The reference is a two part article in two consecutive issues of the journal. Of course I can use two entries, but this imho over the top.

My packages used might be outdated:

```
 *File List*
 scrbook.cls    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script document class (book)
scrkbase.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent bas
ics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    2014/05/08 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize10pt.clo    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script font size class option (10pt)
typearea.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (type area)
inputenc.sty    2014/04/30 v1.2b Input encoding file
  latin1.def    2014/04/30 v1.2b Input encoding file
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
   babel.sty    2014/03/24 3.9k The Babel package
 ngerman.ldf    2013/12/13 v2.7 German support for babel (new orthography)
biblatex.sty    2013/11/25 v2.8a programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex2.sty    2013/11/25 v2.8a programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB
)
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  blx-dm.def
authoryear.dbx
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.def
blx-natbib.def    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
standard.bbx    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
authoryear.bbx    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
authoryear.cbx    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.cfg
  german.lbx    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
 ngerman.lbx    2013/11/25 v2.8a biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
     Lit.bbl
  t1cmss.fd    1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definit
```

Comment: I get the output I expected. In my tests the page numbers were included. So I'm a bit confused about your question. What do you get? What would you expect (i.e. what is 'the desired output')? Can you please show us a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and not just code snippets?

Comment: The document appears to compile as expected under pdfLaTeX if one adds the instructions `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to the preamble.

Comment: Indeed, if I ignore the problems about umlauts, which can be fixed with the right encoding and Mico's suggestion I get what I expected. If I use `pages={{S.~74--78 und 90--95}},` I get what you desired as well.

Comment: Really interesting. Does anyone have an idea why I do not get this result?

Comment: Please tell us which TeX distribution and which versions of `biblatex` and `biber` you use.

Comment: No. What versions of `biblatex`, Biber are you using? Do you get any warnings in the `.log` or `.blg` file? (I trust you really tested the MWE and not just your actual document?)

Comment: Please see above, I added it to my question.   No warnings or errors in the log-file neither in the blg-file.

Comment: OK, you seem to be stuck with a TeX distribution from almost three years ago. Could you update? If you use TeX live you need to install the newest TeX live 2016.

Comment: Yes, I will update with TL 2016. Tomorrow! You will be informed about the outcome.

Comment: You got it! After updating to TL 2016 I obtain the same results as you. Many thanks for the hint! -- But I am not quite sure (I wasn't it before) whether this is the optimal bibtex entry for this reference (two parts in one reference with different pages). Does anyone have an idea how to improve it?

Comment: Have a look at [Is it possible to have several entries in a bibtex-date field?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/232526/35864) (yes, the title doesn't really look like this is what you are after, but have a look at the answer). If you don't want to modify your style your current solution is probably the quickest and easiest.

Comment: Thanks for your link. As you probably assumed, regarding my problem this is like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. As I need this special kind of entry very rarely, I will stick with my old 'solution' - quick & dirty as it is.

Comment: Brilliant. Any idea what should happen to this question now that it is answered? Do you want an 'update your TeX distribution' answer? Or something else?

Comment: I am not sure about the customs here, but this would be correct of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With current versions of the packages involved you get the expected output with

```
@article{Heuberger99,
  author  = {Heuberger, Albert and Volker Gehrmann},
  title   = {{Störsichere Übertragung in den ISM-Bändern}},
  journal = {Elektronik},
  year    = 1999,
  pages   = {{S.~74--78 und 90--95}},
  number  = {{19 und 20}},
}
```

So you should update your TeX distribution.